# Python script in Raspbian Jessie runs great when started from IDLE but auto-closes when started from Terminal via shell/batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, terminal, raspbian

I want another user to be able to run my Python application, so I made a shell/batch file to launch it.  It has the shebang header, chmod set and launches correctly in terminal, however it closes (The script running in Term) with no warning when it shouldn't.

When I open the Python file in IDLE and select Run->Run Module, it runs indefinitely.

I suppose this could be happening because when a running python script encounters an error or exception when run through IDLE, the exception/error is displayed in red so that it can be debugged.  My assumption is that the reason Terminal disappears so fast is because it immediately exits when it comes across something it doesn't know how to handle.

What's puzzling me is that over the course of many, many hours of debugging, I feel I've managed to code out any bug that the script would ever encounter.
I feel this is true because the program can run for days on end, problem-free when launched from IDLE.

Comment: I suspect a problem with your mainloop call, but we need to see a [mcve]

Comment: `IDLE` uses `tkinter` so it executs `mainloop()` which runs `IDLE` and your code. But normally you have to add `mainloop()` to your code to run it.

Comment: I'm using `win.update_idletasks()` and `win.update()` instead of `mainloop()` as I want to be able to refresh StringVars and other GUI components without having to leave the method that the button clicks calls.

Calling `mainloop()` leaves the button pressed down until the `command = function()` completes, preventing the UI from refreshing or anything else from happening.